# Windows Hooks with golang

Tags: c, windows, winapi, go, keyboard-hook

I'm writing an application that will make use of the Win32 API WH_KEYBOARD hook so that it can be activated (i.e., displayed in the foreground) without having focus.  The callback, naturally, is a function pointer (of type HOOKPROC).  A lot of the documentation for WH_KEYBOARD and WH_KEYBOARD_LL says that the callback has to reside in a DLL and cannot directly be in an EXE, however I've found that not to be true in Windows XP and above so I think that's a historical quirk.

The application is written in Go.  I'm aware of (and have contributed to) [github.com/AllenDang/w32](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32), but I don't see anything that can be used to deal with function pointers.  Due to the structure of goroutines, is this even possible?  I know that calling C from Go is simple, but what does one do about function pointers for callbacks like this?

Right now my kludge is to write an EXE that sends a message via the standard output, compile it separately, include it using `go-bindata` and at runtime write this to a temporary file and execute it, while a goroutine watches that process's standard output.  It makes me cringe.  Please tell me there's a better way without using an external process and awful IPC hackery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the wiki page about [cgo](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo).

You will have to define the callback in C and then call your Go function from it:

First export your Go callback :

```
//export gocb
func gocb() {

}
```

Then define your callback in say `hook.c`

```
#include "_cgo_export.h"

void c_callback() {
    gocb();
}
```

*It's my code and I hacked it up to test something, never had the time to clean it up after that.*

Here's an (ugly ugly) example: https://github.com/OneOfOne/go-nfqueue/blob/master/nfqueue.go#L129, https://github.com/OneOfOne/go-nfqueue/blob/master/nfqueue.h and https://github.com/OneOfOne/go-nfqueue/blob/master/nfqueue.c#L49

Comment: I was researching this a few months ago and must have missed that if it's not new.  Thanks very much!

Comment: It's been a part of Go for a while, probably since 1.0 or 1.1